# Mikrotik - Access from VPN to LAN

Tags: vpn, routing, mikrotik

There is a VPN server on Mikrotik to connect from internet to the network behind the router. Like:

```
LAN -> Mikrotik <-> VPN <- PC in internet
```

I can connect but can't access PCs on LAN when I connect from outside.
Here's IP pools:

```
dhcp: 192.168.10.100 - 192.168.10.200
vpn: 192.168.89.2 - 192.168.89.100
```

What rules I need to setup to have access from outside via VPN to PCs in local network?

Answer (score 0):

you need add route in PC. For windows example
route add -p 192.168.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.89.2